# How to describe a topic using kafka client in Python

Tags: python, kafka-python

I'm beginner to kafka client in python, i need some help to describe the topics using the client.

I was able to list all my kafka topics using the following code:-

```
consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(group_id='test', bootstrap_servers=['kafka1'])
topicList = consumer.topics()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After referring multiple articles and code samples, I was able to do this through describe_configs using confluent_kafka.

Link 1 [[Confluent-kafka-python]](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#)
Link 2 [Git Sample](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/43252122ea6a2fd166fa04c0be5a585c77eb8c2c/tests/test_Admin.py)

Below is my sample code!!

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic, NewPartitions, ConfigResource
import confluent_kafka
import concurrent.futures

#Creation of config
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka1','session.timeout.ms': 6000}
adminClient = AdminClient(conf)
topic_configResource = adminClient.describe_configs([ConfigResource(confluent_kafka.admin.RESOURCE_TOPIC, "myTopic")])
    for j in concurrent.futures.as_completed(iter(topic_configResource.values())):
        config_response = j.result(timeout=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have found how to do it with kafka-python:

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, ConfigResource, ConfigResourceType
KAFKA_URL = "localhost:9092" # kafka broker
KAFKA_TOPIC = "test" # topic name

admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=[KAFKA_URL])
configs = admin_client.describe_configs(config_resources=[ConfigResource(ConfigResourceType.TOPIC, KAFKA_TOPIC)])
config_list = configs.resources[0][4]
```

In **config_list** (list of tuples) you have all the configs for the topic.

Comment: I'm not able to use ConfigResourceType, any idea?

Comment: With Kafka-Python 2.0, configs is a list of DescribeConfigsResponse_v2, so you need:

`configs[0].resources[0][4]`

Answer (score 2):

Refer: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/

1. list_topics provide confluent_kafka.admin.TopicMetadata (topic,
   partitions)
2. kafka.admin.TopicMetadata.partitions provide: confluent_kafka.admin.PartitionMetadata (Partition id, leader, replicas, isrs)

   ```
   from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient
   kafka_admin = AdminClient({"bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers})    
   for topic in topics:    
       x = kafka_admin.list_topics(topic=topic)    
       print x.topics, '\n'    
       for key, value in x.topics.items():    
           for keyy, valuey in value.partitions.items():    
               print keyy, ' Partition id : ', valuey, 'leader : ', valuey.leader,' replica: ', valuey.replicas
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, for Java this functionality (`describeTopics()`) sits within the [KafkaAdminCLient.java](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html#describeTopics-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeTopicsOptions-).

So, I was trying to look for the python equivalent of the same and I discovered the [code repository of kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python).

The documentation (in-line comments) in admin-client equivalent in kafka-python package says the following:

> ```
> describe topics functionality is in ClusterMetadata
> Note: if implemented here, send the request to the controller
> ```

I then switched to [cluster.py file](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/cluster.py) in the same repository. This contains the `topics()` function that you've used to retrieve the list of topics and the following 2 functions that could help you achieve the `describe` functionality:

1. `partitions_for_topic()` - Return set of all partitions for topic (whether available or not)
2. `available_partitions_for_topic()` - Return set of partitions with known leaders

*Note*: I haven't tried this myself so I'm not entierly sure if the behaviour would be identical to what you would see in the result for `kafka-topics --describe ...` command but worth a try.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for explanation Lalit. I looked at the available methods no luck. I was actually looking at getting the retention period per topic which we get through kafka-topics.sh --describe.

Comment: Okay. Fair enough. I'll try and find something but it seems like python libraries are slightly different and not exactly analogous.